# Loadbalancing SFTP with TCP connection timed out

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, sftp, amazon-elb

I have a sftp process running on a machine on Amazon EC2. Connecting with Filezilla works flawlessly.

I tried to create an Amazon load balancer over TCP:TCP for this process, internet facing, but I can only get

> Connecting to XXX.elb.amazonaws.com...
>
> Response: fzSftp started, protocol_version=6
>
> Command:  open "XXX.elb.amazonaws.com" 22
>
> Error:    Network error: Connection timed out
>
> Error:    Could not connect to server
>
> Status:   Waiting to retry...
>
> Status:   Connecting to XXX.elb.amazonaws.com...
>
> Response: fzSftp started, protocol_version=6
>
> Command:  open "XXX.elb.amazonaws.com" 22
>
> Error:    Network error: Connection timed out
>
> Error:    Could not connect to server

when trying to connect with Filezilla. It seems that I can't connect through the TCP loadbalancer ( I double checked the ports used and the health check is passing: 'InService' ). How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Just found out that the security group I used did not authorize the use of the specified ports.

The solution is consequently to create a new security group with the right ports allowed, or open new ports on the current security group.